# Fetching via category_name from PHP to Android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I've been trying to fetch all the data in my table via category name, it works if I fetched it via category_id in the tbl_menu but I decided to change it to fetch via category_name (named category in the tbl_menu). But it doesn't fetch and logcat isn't much help.

This is the table for my categories(tbl_category), it's not really relevant since it's just a table for when I add products and this is where it fetches categories.

[image]

This is the table for my products(tbl_menu) this is where it supposed to fetch the products via category column.

[image]

Now, I think my api is right but I may be wrong since it's supposed to be fetching in the category.

get-menu-data-by-category-id.php

```
<?php
    include_once('../includes/connect_database.php'); 
    include_once('../includes/variables.php');

    if(isset($_GET['accesskey']) && isset($_GET['category'])) {
        $access_key_received = $_GET['accesskey'];
        $category = $_GET['category'];

        if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
            $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
        }else{
            $keyword = "";
        }

        if($access_key_received == $access_key){
            if($keyword == ""){
                // find menu by category id in menu table
                $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image 
                    FROM tbl_menu 
                    WHERE Category = ".$category." 
                    ORDER BY Menu_ID DESC";
            }else{
                // find menu by category id and keyword in menu table
                $sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image 
                    FROM tbl_menu 
                    WHERE Menu_name LIKE '%".$keyword."%' AND Category = ".$category." 
                    ORDER BY Menu_ID DESC";
            }

            $result = $connect->query($sql_query) or die("Error : ".mysql_error());

            $menus = array();
            while($menu = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $menus[] = array('Menu'=>$menu);
            }

            // create json output
            $output = json_encode(array('data' => $menus));
        }else{
            die('accesskey is incorrect.');
        }
    } else {
        die('accesskey and category are required.');
    }

    //Output the output.
    echo $output;

    include_once('../includes/close_database.php'); 
?>
```

When a category is clicked it gives a putextra to the next activity (ActivityMenuList.java). CTRL+F point of interest #3

ActivityCategoryList.java

```
package com.emman.motg;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityCategoryList extends Activity {

    GridView listCategory;
    ProgressBar prgLoading;
    TextView txtAlert;

    // declare adapter object to create custom category list
    AdapterCategoryList cla;

    // create arraylist variables to store data from server
    static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
    static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();

    String CategoryAPI;
    int IOConnect = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category_list);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        bar.setTitle("Category");

        prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
        listCategory = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.listCategory);
        txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

        cla = new AdapterCategoryList(ActivityCategoryList.this);

        // category API url
        CategoryAPI = Constant.CategoryAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey;

        // call asynctask class to request data from server
        new getDataTask().execute();

        // event listener to handle list when clicked
        listCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // go to menu page
                Intent iMenuList = new Intent(ActivityCategoryList.this, ActivityMenuList.class);
                iMenuList.putExtra("category_id", Category_ID.get(position));
                iMenuList.putExtra("category", Category_name.get(position));//point of interest #3
                startActivity(iMenuList);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cart:
            // refresh action
            Intent iMyOrder = new Intent(ActivityCategoryList.this, ActivityCart.class);
            startActivity(iMyOrder);
            overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            return true;

        case R.id.refresh:
            IOConnect = 0;
            listCategory.invalidateViews();
            clearData();
            new getDataTask().execute();
            return true;

        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            this.finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // clear arraylist variables before used
    void clearData(){
        Category_ID.clear();
        Category_name.clear();
        Category_image.clear();
    }

    // asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
    public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        // show progressbar first
        getDataTask(){
            if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
                txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background
            parseJSONData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
            prgLoading.setVisibility(8);

            // if internet connection and data available show data on list
            // otherwise, show alert text
            if((Category_ID.size() > 0) && (IOConnect == 0)){
                listCategory.setVisibility(0);
                listCategory.setAdapter(cla);
            }else{
                txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
            }
        }
    }

    // method to parse json data from server
    public void parseJSONData(){

        clearData();

        try {
            // request data from Category API
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(CategoryAPI);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

            String line;
            String str = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                str += line;
            }

            // parse json data and store into arraylist variables
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

                JSONObject category = object.getJSONObject("Category");

                Category_ID.add(Long.parseLong(category.getString("Category_ID")));
                Category_name.add(category.getString("Category_name"));
//              Category_image.add(category.getString("Category_image"));
                Log.d("Category name", Category_name.get(i));

            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            IOConnect = 1;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //cla.imageLoader.clearCache();
        listCategory.setAdapter(null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
    {
        // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
    }

}
```

In this activity, point of interest #1 gets the extra and puts it in a variable

ActivityMenuList.java

```
package com.emman.motg;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityMenuList extends Activity {

    ListView listMenu;
    ProgressBar prgLoading;
    //TextView txtTitle;
    EditText edtKeyword;
    ImageButton btnSearch;
    TextView txtAlert;

    // declare static variable to store tax and currency symbol
    static double Tax;
    static String Currency;

    // declare adapter object to create custom menu list
    AdapterMenuList mla;

    // create arraylist variables to store data from server
    static ArrayList<Long> Menu_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
    static ArrayList<String> Menu_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<Double> Menu_price = new ArrayList<Double>();
    static ArrayList<String> Menu_image = new ArrayList<String>();

    String MenuAPI;
    String TaxCurrencyAPI;
    int IOConnect = 0;
    long Category_ID;
    String Category_name;
    String Keyword;

    // create price format
    DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_list);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
        bar.setTitle("Product");
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
        listMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMenu);
        edtKeyword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtKeyword);
        btnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

        // menu API url
        MenuAPI = Constant.MenuAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey+"&category=";
        // tax and currency API url
        TaxCurrencyAPI = Constant.TaxCurrencyAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey;

        // get category id and category name that sent from previous page
        Intent iGet = getIntent();
        Category_ID = iGet.getLongExtra("category_id",0);
        Category_name = iGet.getStringExtra("category");//point of interest #1
        MenuAPI += Category_name;

        // set category name to textview
//        txtTitle.setText(Category_name);

        mla = new AdapterMenuList(ActivityMenuList.this);

        // call asynctask class to request tax and currency data from server
        new getTaxCurrency().execute();

        // event listener to handle search button when clicked
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // get keyword and send it to server
                try {
                    Keyword = URLEncoder.encode(edtKeyword.getText().toString(), "utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                MenuAPI += "&keyword="+Keyword;
                IOConnect = 0;
                listMenu.invalidateViews();
                clearData();
                new getDataTask().execute();
            }
        });

        // event listener to handle list when clicked
        listMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // go to menu detail page
                Intent iDetail = new Intent(ActivityMenuList.this, ActivityMenuDetail.class);
                iDetail.putExtra("menu_id", Menu_ID.get(position));
                startActivity(iDetail);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            }
        });       

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category, menu);

//      final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
//        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
//          
//          @Override
//            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {                            
//                return true;
//            }  
//          
//          @Override
//            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
//              try {
//                  Keyword = URLEncoder.encode(query.toString(), "utf-8");
//              } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
//                  e.printStackTrace();    
//              }
//              
//              MenuAPI += "&keyword="+Keyword;
//              IOConnect = 0;
//              listMenu.invalidateViews();
//              clearData();
//              new getDataTask().execute();  
//                
//                return true;
//            }          
//        });
//        
//        searchView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
//
//            @Override
//            public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View arg0) {
//              IOConnect = 0;
//              listMenu.invalidateViews();
//              clearData();
//              new getDataTask().execute();
//            }
//
//            @Override
//            public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View arg0) {
//                // search was opened
//            }
//        });

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cart:
            // refresh action
            Intent iMyOrder = new Intent(ActivityMenuList.this, ActivityCart.class);
            startActivity(iMyOrder);
            overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
            return true;

        case R.id.refresh:
            IOConnect = 0;
            listMenu.invalidateViews();
            clearData();
            new getDataTask().execute();
            return true;            

        case android.R.id.home:
            // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
            this.finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
    public class getTaxCurrency extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        // show progressbar first
        getTaxCurrency(){
            if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
                txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background
            parseJSONDataTax();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
            prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
            // if internet connection and data available request menu data from server
            // otherwise, show alert text
            if((Currency != null) && IOConnect == 0){
                new getDataTask().execute();
            }else{
                txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
            }
        }
    }

    // method to parse json data from server
    public void parseJSONDataTax(){
        try {
            // request data from tax and currency API
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(TaxCurrencyAPI);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

            String line;
            String str = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                str += line;
            }


            // parse json data and store into tax and currency variables
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

            JSONObject object_tax = data.getJSONObject(0); 
            JSONObject tax = object_tax.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

            Tax = Double.parseDouble(tax.getString("Value"));

            JSONObject object_currency = data.getJSONObject(1); 
            JSONObject currency = object_currency.getJSONObject("tax_n_currency");

            Currency = currency.getString("Value");


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            IOConnect = 1;
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    // clear arraylist variables before used
    void clearData(){
        Menu_ID.clear();
        Menu_name.clear();
        Menu_price.clear();
        Menu_image.clear();
    }

    // asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
    public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        // show progressbar first
        getDataTask(){
            if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
                prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
                txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // parse json data from server in background
            parseJSONData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
            prgLoading.setVisibility(8);

            // if data available show data on list
            // otherwise, show alert text
            if(Menu_ID.size() > 0){
                listMenu.setVisibility(0);
                listMenu.setAdapter(mla);
            }else{
                txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
            }

        }
    }

    // method to parse json data from server
    public void parseJSONData(){

        clearData();

        try {
            // request data from menu API
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
            HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuAPI);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

            String line;
            String str = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                str += line;
            }

            // parse json data and store into arraylist variables
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);//point of interest #2
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

                JSONObject menu = object.getJSONObject("Menu");

                Menu_ID.add(Long.parseLong(menu.getString("Menu_ID")));
                Menu_name.add(menu.getString("Menu_name"));
                Menu_price.add(Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price"))));
                Menu_image.add(menu.getString("Menu_image"));

            }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //mla.imageLoader.clearCache();
        listMenu.setAdapter(null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
    {
        // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
    }


}
```

Finally, the only information that logcat shows is the `JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` in point of interest #2, I do not know why it is doing that but it is certainly not showing when I had it fetching via category_id. I'm very sorry for the long post but I just wanted to get as much information as possible to try to get help because I'm at my wits end here. Let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image 
                    FROM tbl_menu 
                    WHERE Category = ".$category." 
                    ORDER BY Menu_ID DESC";
```

Can you please try by changing to :

```
$sql_query = "SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_name, Price, Menu_image 
                    FROM tbl_menu 
                    WHERE Category = '".$category."' 
                    ORDER BY Menu_ID DESC";
```